# Minimal surfaces with infinite Morse index

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, minimal-surfaces

Are there examples of complete minimal surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with infinite Morse index and finite topology and finite number of ends? (I don't expect such examples to be embedded...)

Any help/reference would be very much appreciated Thanks!